# gnuplot pgn output without generating plot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

Is it possible to generate a .png output without generating a plot?. I have my data set that I have to draw in a .png to later on spc to my server.

So far all the examples I have seen use the 'plot' instruction which generates the plot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it took me a bit of playing with the command but got it to work. 
all you gotta do is configure the output to be a .png file BEFORE doing the plot in the command order.

e.g: gnuplot -e 'set term png;set output"data_print.png";plot"calibration.dat"'